# How to change the textContent o just text of a <span> without changing the rest of the content

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

I want to change the text of a span with a checkbox inside like this:

```js
function checkChange(){
       document.getElementById("span1").textContent="red";}
```

```html
<span id="span1" style="color:darkolivegreen;font-weight:bold">
    <input id="check1" type='checkbox' onclick="checkChange();">blue
</span>
```

the result is this:
< span style='color:darkolivegreen;font-weight:bold'>red< /span>"
And the checkbox disapears.
It's the same with innerHTML.
How can I change the text without afecting other fields inside my span

Comment: Just re-add your checkbox in the text as well as the text since the textbox gets wiped out when you change the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

There is no "just the text" node; you can have more than one:

```
<span id="span1" style="color:darkolivegreen;font-weight:bold">
    first text node in span
    <input id="check1" type='checkbox' onclick="checkChange();">
    second text node in span
</span>
```

Check out what this JS code prints:

```
var sp = document.getElementById("span1");
for (var n = 0 ; n <sp.childNodes.length; n++){
    if (sp.childNodes[n].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        console.log("found text \""+sp.childNodes[n].nodeValue+"\" in node "+n)
    }
}
```

> found text "        first text node in span
>           " in node 0
>
> found text "
>           second text node in span" in node 2

So first you need to find the node you're looking to change, and then you can change it.

The code below changes the value of each text node:

```
var sp = document.getElementById("span1");
for (var n = 0 ; n <sp.childNodes.length; n++){
    if (sp.childNodes[n].nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
        sp.childNodes[n].nodeValue = "new text node value";
    }
}
```

Note that I added newlines for readability in the text below; those newlines are actually a part of the text node values.

> ```
> <span id="span1" style="color: darkolivegreen; font-weight: bold;">
>     new text node value
>     <input id="check1" type="checkbox" onclick="checkChange();">
>     new text node value
> </span>
> ```

Only tested in Chrome so far...

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkChange(){
      var elem = document.getElementById("span1");
      for (var i = 0; i < elem.childNodes.length; i++) {
          var curNode = elem.childNodes[i];
          if ((curNode.nodeValue ? curNode.nodeValue : "").match(/.*blue.*/)) {
              curNode.nodeValue = "red";
          }
      }

}
```

```html
<span id="span1" style="color:darkolivegreen;font-weight:bold">
<input id="check1" type='checkbox' onclick="checkChange();">
  blue
</span>
```

Answer (score -2):

Change your html to something like this:

```
<span id="span1" style="color:darkolivegreen;font-weight:bold">
    <input id="check1" type='checkbox' onclick="checkChange();">
    <span id="2">blue</span>
</span>
```

and your javascript to something like this:

```
function checkChange(){
    document.getElementById("span2").textContent="red";
}
```